# Puma Web Server No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)

Tags: ruby, heroku, puma, procfile

Attempting to use Puma Web Server with heroku for application. I have created a Procfile called "Procfile" with the following.

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I also have a config/puma.rb file with the following.

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do 
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I receive the following warning in terminal

```
$git push heroku master

###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
```

Comment: Post the error so we can better evaluate the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more information from you. What is the exact error? Please read "[ask]".

Comment: Is your Procfile in the app's root folder and did you commit it before you pushed?

Comment: Yes! When I  "$git commit -m "Procfile":  "$nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Comment: Are you using the correct casing? `Procfile` - do you see it in the file listing if you do `heroku run bash` and perform an `ls`

Comment: @JohnBeynon Just followed your instructions! Procfile shows up like this `Procfile.rtf`. Could this be the problem, if so, how do I go to change that, in the root directory it is named Procfile only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$git run bash
```

Bash confirmed it was running

```
$ls
```

All the files were shown. `Procfile` was being recognized with an extension as `Procfile.rtf`.

Deleted previous Procfile. Created another Procfile and made sure there was no extensions. Then ran the following:

```
$Git add .
$Git commit -m "Procfile" 
$Git push heroku master
```